# find minimum dot product in a set of two-dimension vectors

Tags: data-structures, geometry

Suppose you have `n(n<=50000)` two-dimension vectors `pi=(xi,yi)`,for every `1<=i<=n`,find `1<=j<=n` that `minimize dot(pi,pj)`,where `dot(pi,pj)=xi*xj+yi*yj`;

Is there any solution can get the correct answer efficiently?
upd:`|xi,yi|<=100`

Comment: Do you know anything about the relative magnitudes of the vectors? You might be able to get some mileage out of the fact that a dot b = |a||b| cos theta, where theta is the angle between the vectors.